# How can I use glReadPixels without hWnd?

Tags: windows, opengl, pixel

I succeeded to read pixels from DC which OpenGL rendered on.
Here is a part of my code.

```
void COpenGLWnd::OffscreenRender
    (/* IN parameters */ int transitionID, int counts, int directionID,
    /* OUT parameters */ BYTE* pPixelArray)
{
    HDC hDC = ::GetDC(m_hWnd);
    SetDCPixelFormat(hDC);

    HGLRC hRC = wglCreateContext(hDC);
    VERIFY(wglMakeCurrent(hDC, hRC));

    for(int i = 0; i < counts; i++)
    {
        GLFadeinRender((GLfloat)(i+1) / (GLfloat)counts);

        BYTE* data = (BYTE*) malloc(m_BmpSize);
        glReadBuffer(GL_BACK);
        glReadPixels(0,0,m_BmpWidth,m_BmpHeight,GL_BGR_EXT,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

        memcpy(&pPixelArray[i * m_BmpSize], data, m_BmpSize);
        free(data);
    }

    wglMakeCurrent(hDC, NULL);
    wglDeleteContext(hRC);
    ::ReleaseDC(m_hWnd, hDC);
}
```

It  works very well, but I want to use glReadPixels without hWnd. I heard that PBO or FBO may help for this situation but I cannot make it. Here is the code that I tried to render with PBO.

```
void COpenGLWnd::OffscreenRender
    (/* IN parameters */ int transitionID, int counts, int directionID,
    /* OUT parameters */ BYTE* pPixelArray)
{
    GLuint pbo;
    glGenBuffersARB(1,&pbo);
    glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_ARB, pbo);
    glBufferDataARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_ARB, m_BmpSize, NULL, GL_STREAM_READ_ARB);
    glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_ARB, 0);

    for(int i = 0; i < counts; i++)
    {
        glReadBuffer(GL_BACK);
        glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_ARB, pbo);

        GLFadeinRender((GLfloat)(i+1) / (GLfloat)counts);

        glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_ARB, pbo);
        //glReadBuffer(GL_BACK);
        glReadPixels(0,0,m_BmpWidth,m_BmpHeight,GL_BGR_EXT,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
        BYTE* data = (BYTE*) glMapBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_ARB, GL_READ_ONLY_ARB);

        memcpy(&pPixelArray[i * m_BmpSize], data, m_BmpSize);

        if(data)
        {
            glUnmapBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_ARB);
        }

        glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_ARB,0);
    }

    glDeleteBuffers(1,&pbo);
}
```

But nothing happened at `glReadPixels`. No pixels read. 
So can I off-screen render and read pixels without using `hWnd`?

Comment: Well, first of all the only reason you need an `hWnd` at all in this code is to set the render context to your window. If you use an off-screen solution like FBOs you still need a render context. I get the impression your actual question here is: *"How do I render without a window?"* You can use a memory device context / WGL pbuffer (not to be confused with a PBO), or a hidden window. But fundamentally you ***still*** need a render context, and that is what your second attempt at coding this is lacking.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Then you mean still I need to use HGLRC and HDC with using WGL_ARB_buffer? Could you tell me how to use WGL_ARB_buffer? thanks!